# How to treat csv column as date-time

Tags: excel

I have a CSV file where one of the columns is a string representation of a date in the form 'dd.mm.yy@hh:mm:ss'. I want excel to read this as a date format, so it can sort, filter, etc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Data / Text to columns wizard.

- Step 1:  Delimited
- Step 2:  Delimiters  Other:  @
- Step 3:  Select the first column (the date part) and for Column Data
  Format select Date: DMY

You will probably have to reformat the date column by removing the hyperlink and then applying the desired date format

The above could be automated, if necessary.

If you need both in the same column, you can add them.